# ASP.Net Core Web API throwing 404 error when published on IIS 10 works without IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-webapi

we are upgrading our servers and moved the asp.net core web api to the new servers with the following framework and runtime versions.
.net framework 4.7
.net core runtime 2.2.6
.net core windows server hosting 2.2.6
IIS URL rewrite Module

Getting a 404 error when trying to browse the application from IIS. Same error from postman too.
But when I run it from VS, I get the swagger screen and am able to post requests and get a response too. I tried uninstalling the runtime and hosting modules changing the apppool settings.
Currently the appPool is set to Networkservice, Unmanaged code, tried all the settings for appPoolIdentity. Nothing worked.
Tried enabling the FailedRequestTracing and this is what I see.
Looking for any helpful advices. thanks

[image]

Comment: .NET Core 2.2 is end of life, so not much to discuss further if you don't upgrade to a supported version. Besides, such 404.0 can be simply caused by invalid URL you use. ASP.NET Core relies on proper URLs to trigger proper routing rules so as to generate responses for incoming requests. You get 404.0 when none of the routing rules leads to a valid response.

Comment: How did you publish your app to IIS, is there any tutorial? According to your description, your app worked well in local side, did you modify some configurations in IIS?

Comment: Check the URL. Not only the swagger endpoint, but also the endpoints of the controller.

Comment: this is still working fine in the old servers. Just on the new servers is the issue. No changes made, just copied the code from the old servers to the new ones.

Comment: Also, I see that an empty log file is getting created inside the folder where the published code is.